# Filter list of Object in Rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I want to filter `List<Object>` based on **query** from user and then return `List<Object>` to him/her.I found out how to filter items But the problem is I don't know how return `List<Object>`. I also see some approach which iterate and call `flatMap` each time But I didn't think it's an elegant way.

This is my last attempt:

```
      Observable.from(my_list_of_object)
                    .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .filter(new Func1<MyObject, Boolean>() {
                        @Override
                        public Boolean call(MyObject o) {
                            return o.getName().contains(query); //filtering
                        }
                    })
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())

                   //problem is here and I dont know how 
                   //to convert filtered Item to list
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use `toList()` operator.
Check the [documentation.](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/to.html)

```
      Observable.from(my_list_of_object)
                    .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .filter(new Func1<MyObject, Boolean>() {
                        @Override
                        public Boolean call(MyObject o) {
                            return o.getName().contains(query); //filtering
                        }
                    })
                    .toList()
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
```

You can find more extensive list of aggregate operators [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Mathematical-and-Aggregate-Operators).